# Finding Length of Dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to find the length of dask dataframe using `len(dataframe[column])` but everytime i try to execute this i get an error:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 238, in _feed
    send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 200, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 280, in _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 232] The pipe is being closed
distributed.nanny - ERROR - Nanny failed to start process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\nanny.py", line 575, in start
    await self.process.start()
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\process.py", line 34, in _call_and_set_future
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\distributed\process.py", line 202, in _start
    process.start()
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 948, in reduce_pipe_connection
    dh = reduction.DupHandle(conn.fileno(), access)
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 170, in fileno
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\thakneh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 136, in _check_closed
    raise OSError("handle is closed")
OSError: handle is closed
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
```

My dask dataframe has got 10 million rows. Is there any way i can get through this error.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. You may need to use more partitions for your dataframe given the memory constraints on your cluster.

Answer (score -1):

I feel that finding the length of a column will not be so straight forward because Dask might be building a data frame from various sources - something similar why you can get `.head()` on a dataframe, but need to do something extra do do `.tail()`.

Since you are using such a big dataframe, I believe Python will load anything inside `len()` into memory.

I got two suggestions but I'm not entirely sure they won't trigger the same exception.

### Using `pipe`

Let's see if this will work, you can try to use `pipe` on your column and pass `len` to it, perhaps that could work.

```py
dataframe["column"].pipe(len)
```

For reference here's the [pipe documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.pipe)

### Partitions

One thing that I'm thinking that it could help is if you partition your column into chunks, that might help to keep your memory usage low, the only issue is that you have to do some guest work on how big these partitions will be.

Another thing you will have to keep track is the length of each partition, this could be a bit messy and I feel that there must be a better way to do it tbh.

```py
length = 0

len += dataframe["column"].partitions[:10000]
len += dataframe["column"].partitions[:20000]
```

Of course, you could try to use a loop to make the code a bit cleaner.

For reference here's the documentation for [`dataframe.partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.partitions)

Please let me know if any of these work, I hope I can help you.

Comment: `df.partitions[:20000]` may not be doing what you think it's doing. This will return the first 20,000 partitions of the dask dataframe. This isn't the length or number of rows, nor can it be added to an integer.

Comment: Thank you for that Nick, I wasn't sure if this could be a way to do it, I'm thinking that pipe or a dask.delayed might be the only way to get the length of a column?

Comment: "I believe Python will load anything inside len() into memory" - no, this is not generally true